# Kube2IAM Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam

I was looking at the github docs of setting up and configuring kube2iam. It states the following :

`It is necessary to create an IAM role which can assume other roles and assign it to each kubernetes worker.`

`The roles that will be assumed must have a Trust Relationship which allows them to be assumed by the kubernetes worker role`

Am I correct in saying two IAM Roles are required. The first IAM Role will have permissions for the kubernetes node/s to have permissions to assume IAM Roles ,whilst the second IAM Role will have permissions for the worker role (The first IAM Role) to assume a role with whatever permissions is has set.

Is my understand of this correct ? Also once I create an IAM role which can assume other roles , how do I assign this to each kubernetes worker ? Is this done manually by myself or does kube2iam deal with this ?

Docs : https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam